# find duplicate entries in db

Tags: mysql

I need to find duplicate entries in my db table. There has to be only one row per table where certain field matches an ID. How do I structure my query to find if certain field value is repeated more than once?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(*),  FIELD_NAME from TABLE_NAME group by FIELD_NAME HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```